# Import library could not be resolved Pylance Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, libraries, unresolved-external, pylance

I am trying to do a monte carlo simulation with different code but my program doesn't run because the different libraries like time, and random, and the apis are not recognizable for visual studio Code.
I have watched different videos for solution but I haven't find the solution to run my program.
--------------------------EDIT-------------------
I change the interpreter to the 3.10.7 version in my computer and apparently run all other libraries except these ones. What do I do?

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import *dash_bootstrap_components* as dbc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import plotly.express as px
import simulategames
from *IPython.display* import clear_output
```

*dash_bootstrap_ components and *IPython.display are the ones highlighted in visual studio code.
Also, the others that are not highlighted, they are still not recognized even if I did the pip install library

I expected for it to run after doing a virtual environment, but It didn't work

Comment: Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code are two different things. Can you please [edit] to use the correct terminology?

Comment: Can you please [edit] to _add transcriptions_ of your image of code into an actual code block? [See here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) for why. See [/editing-help](/editing-help#code) for how to format code blocks. You can use code comments to indicate which parts have problem underlining in the code block transcription.

Comment: @starball Thank you for your contribution, I will make the change right away.